# str() conversion not working

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I hope someone can help me. I've been going with this all day. I am trying to have users enter a telephone number, which can include text, such as `"800-FLOWERS"`. I want to print the output as just numbers, but I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Here is my code:

```
keypad = {'a':2, 'A':2, 'b':2, 'B':2, 'c':2, 'C':2,
          'd':3, 'D':3, 'e':3, 'E':3, 'f':3, 'F':3,
          'g':4, 'G':4, 'h':4, 'H':4, 'i':4, 'I':4,
          'j':5, 'J':5, 'k':5, 'K':5, 'l':5, 'L':5,
          'm':6, 'M':6, 'n':6, 'N':6, 'o':6, 'O':6,
          'p':7, 'P':7, 'q':7, 'Q':7, 'r':7, 'R':7, 's':7, 'S':7,
          't':8, 'T':8, 'u':8, 'U':8, 'v':8, 'V':8,
          'w':9, 'W':9, 'x':9, 'X':9, 'y':9, 'Y':9, 'z':9, 'Z':9}  # Create keypad dict
phone_num = input('Enter a phone number: ')

for key, value in keypad.items():
    phone_num = (phone_num.upper().replace(key, value))
    phone_num = str(phone_num)
    print('The number entered is: %s'% phone_num)
```

Comment: since you are converting the phone_num to upper before replacing the key with the value, you do not need to have both uppercase and smallcase in the keypad dictionary.

Comment: You should consider accepting a solution that helped solve your problem as this indicates to other readers as well what was in fact helpful to solving the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to concatenate a `string` with an `int` type, which is not allowed. You are doing it at this line:

```
phone_num = (phone_num.upper().replace(key, value))
```

Ultimately, what you are doing with replace is trying to put an `int` type in to the `string`. To remedy this, cast `str` on the `value`:

```
phone_num = (phone_num.upper().replace(key, str(value)))
```

Which would then not require you to have the line after, so you can remove this: `phone_num = str(phone_num)`

To demo the exact error, look at this:

```
>>> s = "abc"
>>> s = s.replace('a', 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Furthermore, place your last `print` outside your loop or it will print in every iteration.

Upon fixing your error, the code runs as such:

```
Enter a phone number: 800-FLOWERS
The number entered is: 800-3569377


for key, value in keypad.items():
    phone_num = (phone_num.upper().replace(key, str(value)))
print('The number entered is: %s'% phone_num)
```

## Enhancement to your solution

You can consider doing this a slightly different way. Instead of iterating through your `keypad` dictionary, iterate through the string instead and check if you have an alpha character or not. If you do, then lookup in your dictionary to get the value and cast to a string, otherwise just add the "character" to your new string. Furthermore, and this applies to your original solution as well, since you are casting to `upper` already, your dictionary can be simplified to only one casing:

```
    keypad = {
    'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2,
    'D': 3, 'E': 3, 'F': 3,
    'G': 4, 'H': 4, 'I': 4,
    'J': 5, 'K': 5, 'L': 5,
    'M': 6, 'N': 6, 'O': 6,
    'P': 7, 'Q': 7, 'R': 7,
    'S': 7, 'T': 8, 'U': 8,
    'V': 8, 'W': 9, 'X': 9,
    'Y': 9, 'Z': 9
}
phone_num = input('Enter a phone number: ')

phone_as_digits = ""
for char in phone_num:
    phone_as_digits += str(keypad[char.upper()]) if char.isalpha() else char
print(phone_as_digits)
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your two lines are backwards! First you have to convert the number to a string, and then you can replace each of the characters. It seems that you are doing it after, and that is why it is raising an error.

```
#Switch from this
phone_num = (phone_num.upper().replace(key, value))
phone_num = str(phone_num)

#To this
phone_num = str(phone_num)
phone_num = (phone_num.upper().replace(key, value))

#Or even shorter, this
phone_num = str(phone_num.upper().replace(key, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need upper if you have both combinations, and you should do a raw_input to get the string in python2

```
keypad = {'a':2, 'A':2, 'b':2, 'B':2, 'c':2, 'C':2,
          'd':3, 'D':3, 'e':3, 'E':3, 'f':3, 'F':3,
          'g':4, 'G':4, 'h':4, 'H':4, 'i':4, 'I':4,
          'j':5, 'J':5, 'k':5, 'K':5, 'l':5, 'L':5,
          'm':6, 'M':6, 'n':6, 'N':6, 'o':6, 'O':6,
          'p':7, 'P':7, 'q':7, 'Q':7, 'r':7, 'R':7, 's':7, 'S':7,
          't':8, 'T':8, 'u':8, 'U':8, 'v':8, 'V':8,
          'w':9, 'W':9, 'x':9, 'X':9, 'y':9, 'Y':9, 'z':9, 'Z':9}  # Create keypad dict
phone_num = raw_input('Enter a phone number: ')

for key, value in keypad.items():
    phone_num = phone_num.replace(key,str(value))
print('The number entered is: %s' % phone_num)
```